# Spinner: getContentDescription().toString()

Tags: android

I want to get selected item in Spinner in my java file and try to convert that in string.
I didn't getting any clue for that, so if any body help me here, I feel greatfull to him/her.

Answer (score 4):

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewbyId(R.id.spinner);
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `OnItemSelectedListener` listener to your Spinner object and update a variable?

For example, my very simple Spinner listener looks like this:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            selectedIP = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "Selected IP updated: " + selectedIP + " position: " + position);
        }
    });
```

(`selectedIP` is a String I have specified further up and `TAG` is also a String just containing the class name for logging)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find the selected item and can then ask the adapter (or the list from wich it got the data) for the items value:

```
    int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String val =  backingList.get(pos);
```

See [this class](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/account/AccountStuffActivity.java#L128) for a full example.